# Can I sort results from a PHP query to a MYSQL DB of comics and regroup them under respective titles

Tags: php, mysql, join, grouping

I have 2 tables in a DB.

The first one has the comic titles and volumes:

```
TITLE_LIST:

title_ID  title        volume
-----------------------------
1         Spider-Man    1 
2         Daredevil     6
3         Primordial    1
```

Second one has the issues per say with a column named `title` that correspond to the same column `title` in the first table:

```
COMIC_LIST:

ID title issue  variant         grade qty
-----------------------------------------
1  1      1     Silver Edition  9.8   1
2  2      29    Nakayama B      9.8   1
3  2      25    A               9.8   1
4  2      25    B               9.8   1
5  3      1     A               9.8   1
```

After joining both tables, I get this result:

```
Spider-man 1, volume 1, Silver Edition
Daredevil 29, volume 6, Nakayama B
Daredevil 25, volume 6, A
Daredevil 25, volume 6, B
Primordial 1, volume 1, A
```

But what I would want instead, is this:

```
Spider-Man
Issue 1, volume 1, Silver Edition

Daredevil
Issue 29, volume 6, Nakayama B
Issue 25, volume 6, A
Issue 25, volume 6, B

Primordial
Issue 1, volume 1, A
```

Comment: UNION ALL must help you.

Comment: Oh... I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: Do it in PHP. Whenever the title changes, print a heading.

Comment: SQL returns you a result set.  It looks like you simply want to have an output that reveals the grouping by Title.  Do that in your PHP code.  All you need to do is use a variable to keep track of the Title.  When it changes you have a new group.

Comment: @Barmar can you give me an example by any chance?

Comment: @gview I tried, but I don't know enough about PHP to do that.  I might need a bit of handholding :)

Comment: @MehdiBouhalassa See the linked question.

Comment: @Barmar Excellent, thanks a lot!